# c++ Displaying tiles in monopoly separately (text version)

Tags: c++, io, cout

I'm making a monopoly game, no graphics. I'm trying to figure out a way to output the board (text style) in chunks. AKA out each tile instead of outputting one line at a time. Every time I think of endl it will end the entire line, not just a fraction of it. Any ideas?

It will look something like this (the tiles are a version of my school campus)

[image: monopoly]

Comment: you could have a char bitmap buffer (two dimensional array) to which you draw, and then once you finish, blit the buffer to the screen. Your draw function will be generic, taking an x,y offset and the stuff that it needs to draw.

Comment: You need a way to handle the cursor position on the screen, like ncurses.

Comment: @taoufik would this kind of be like a 2d array? i could change the characters anywhere i need (ex arr[5][10] to arr[10][15] is one monopoly tile and i know where each tile is) and then just output it row by row after modifying with a double for loop. would that work, or would i encounter problems?

Comment: You are correct - your draw method will be drawing on a `char[][]` array. A `char[nRows][nCols]` array that is initially set to the char code produced by a spacebar (or NULL, and then your blit method replaces NULL by a space). And yes, your draw method can use indices to draw (but more like `arr[10+rowOffset][15+collOffset]`)

Comment: awesome, this should work. I'm making an array of strings and using string stream to make it into characters just for the initialization. Thanks for the help and suggestion!